# Is it possible to add custom validation to JSF beans?

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2

It is about validation in JSF. I know that there are two way for validation

1. Bean Validation
2. JSF Validation

I want to write my own validation class. Is it possible to add the custom validation class to JSF beans?

I don't want to have the validation class in my facelett. Only in Bean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can write your own validator class like this:

```
@FacesValidator("customValidator")
public class CustomValidator implements Validator{

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        // do your validation here
    }
}
```

and use it in your facelets:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.myValue}">
  <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

Note that the content of the `@FacesValidator` annotation must match the `validatorId` attribute of `f:validator`.

Furthermore jsf input elements have an `validator` attribute. You can use this attribute to delegate validation to a special method in you backing bean.

with

```
public void validateInput(FacesContext context, 
                          UIComponent component, Object object) {
  // your validation with 'object' here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

Please have a look at here. 
http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2008/07/09/write-your-own-validator-in-jsf/

Comment: It is not what I want. It adds the validation to jsf page.

Comment: It is there, you need to implement Validator interface to create your own validator. What you want exactly?

Comment: In Bean you can check the value with annotations. Something similar. I want to write a validator that validates the input value in Bean. And I don't want to have in facelet

Comment: Why cant you use simple java code to check values in your bean then?